# Who is Clive Handforth meant to be in Little Big Planet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

Clive Handforth (the guy with a notepad for a head) appears to be a parody of something, but I'm not sure what. Simply the "it's grim up north" stereotypical Yorkshireman?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on splattered bits' answer, I think I've remembered what I was reminded of:

[The Testing of Eric Olthwaite](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kzn3KaO2Vyk)

By Michael Palin and Terry Jones - Pythonistas.

Comment: Spot on!  Even down to the accent. Until Media Molecule makes an official statement, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually think of [Monty Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python) whenever the Alliance leaders appear in the game.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with their skits/movies to know who Clive might be based on.

He does remind me a little of [Eeyore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eeyore).

I was just watching the latest season of [The IT Crowd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd), when [Richmond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_IT_Crowd_characters#Richmond_Felicity_Avenal) made a surprise appearance.  I immediately thought of Clive Handforth.  They sound and act a lot alike.  I think, as the original question states, that **Clive *is* meant to be a stereotypical gloomy Yorkshireman**.  Having never been to England, and knowing nothing of the culture or country, this is only a guess.